# Powershell - Calling C# function inside a job

Tags: c#, powershell, powershell-2.0, jobs

I have a PowerShell program with C# code inside.
I want that the C# function will run in a new job.
I tried this-

```
start-job -name Job1 -ScriptBlock {[MyProgram.Program]::Main()}
```

It looks like the job was executed but nothing happened.

Comment: What does "it doesn't work" mean ? Do you have an error message ?

Comment: Cannot work, because scriptblock don't know declaration of c# class.

Comment: @f6a4 so is there a way to execute C# function using start-job?

Comment: @shon Jobs execute in a separate process, so you'll need to compile/execute your C# code in the `{}` scriptblock before calling `Main()`

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen can you please send me an example? I am not sure what you meant

Comment: @shon Show us your whole script (including the C# code)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
start-job -name Job1 -ScriptBlock {

Add-Type -typedef @"

    namespace MyProgram 
    {
        //-----------------------------------------
        public class Program
        //-----------------------------------------
        {

            //-------------------------------------
            public static void Main()
            //-------------------------------------
            {
                // Your c# Code here
            }

        }
    }
"@


[MyProgram.Program]::Main()

}
```